# How do I remove the "Yoast SEO Schema enhancements" box from my profile edit (backend)?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

How do I remove the "Yoast SEO Schema enhancements" box from my profile edit (backend)?
[Yoast SEO Schema enhancements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnNlE.png)

Comment: It's a feature of the paid Yoast offering. Why not ask their support team?

Comment: Did you find out how? Please update

Comment: No, I didn't...

Answer (score 0):

I have been digging on code... I didn't found anything but to apply a `display: none` by css.

Apply this css to the backend of your wordpress:

```css
#yoast-seo-schema,
#yoast-seo-schema + p,
.yoast-settings {
  display: none;
}
```

The `#yoast-seo-schema` will make the title to disappear. The `#yoast-seo-schema + p` makes disappear the next paragraph... and `.yoast-settings` the rest...

It is a fragile solution, but it's better than nothing... remember the fields will still be there....

Comment: Thank u for the formatting!